# Python - How to rearrange datas in array?

Tags: python, arrays

I work with this kind of array, they are straight from a spectrometer (wavelength, intensity) and I had to treat them with python.

```
280.0,1.0
280.4031007751938,1.0
280.8062015503876,1.0
281.2093023255814,1.0
281.61240310077517,1.0
282.015503875969,1.0
282.4186046511628,1.0
282.8217054263566,1.0
283.2248062015504,1.0
283.6279069767442,1.0
284.031007751938,1.0
284.4341085271318,1.0
284.83720930232556,1.0
285.2403100775194,1.0
285.6434108527132,1.0
286.04651162790697,1.0
286.4496124031008,1.0
286.85271317829455,1.0
287.25581395348837,1.0
287.6589147286822,1.0
288.06201550387595,1.0
288.4651162790698,1.0
288.86821705426354,1.0
289.27131782945736,1.0
289.6744186046512,1.0909090909090908
290.07751937984494,1.1818181818181819
```

My problem is that the function which uses these datas in my python program wants an array where wavelength data is separated from intensity by a `:`. This form `280: 0.1,`. So I am looking for a way to replace the `,` by a `:` and put a `,` to separate from other datas. I do not know how to do that, is NumPy able to do that ?

I also look for a way to extract some specific values (with a definable step) from the starting data array.

I also want to remove all decimals for the wavelength as you can see in the below expected example but I think I will be able to deal with this part.

The idea is to have, at the end, such a array :

```
data_sample = {380: 11.0,
           385: 11.0,
           390: 11.0,
           395: 11.545454545454545,
           400: 12.363636363636363,
           405: 13.454545454545455,
           410: 14.0,
           415: 14.181818181818182,
           420: 15.363636363636363,}
```

I hope I succeed to well describe what I am trying to do and you can help me or guide me towards answers.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What is the input format of your data? Text file? Could you add a snipet of your function to understand how the array is structured?

Comment: Yes it is a text file. Well I use a library called Colour and the function 'colour.SpectralDistribution'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the *colour.SpectralDistribution* method you need to pass a dictionary as argument where **wavelength** is the key and **intensity** the value.

Basically, for each line you read in your input file you have to:

- split it based on the comma separator to retrieve the **wavelength** at the leftend and the **intensity** at the rightend
- convert values from string to float + round the **wavelength** value
- push the **wavelength** and  **intensity** as key/value pair into a dictionary.

You can achieve this goal like so:

```
with open("raw_data.txt", "r") as raw_data_file:
  lines = [line.rstrip("\n").split(",") for line in raw_data_file]
  
spectral_distribution_input = {
  round(float(wavelength)): float(intensity) for (wavelength, intensity) in lines
}
```